# B2C OpenId Connect jwt Token Validation in web api

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, jwt, openid, .net-6.0

I've been struggling with this token validation and the Microsoft documentation didn't offer any kind of help.
I'm using B2C with identity provider, I am using angular frontend and asp.net core api as backend.
I am able to login using b2c and the user is being validated and i'm getting the following claim:

```
{
"homeAccountId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-b2c_1_susi.xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"environment": "xxxxxxxxxxxx.b2clogin.com",
"tenantId": "",
"username": "jad.fakhoury@xxxxxxxxx.com",
"localAccountId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"name": "Jad Fakhoury",
"idTokenClaims": {
    "exp": 1662892072,
    "nbf": 1662888472,
    "ver": "1.0",
    "iss": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/",
    "sub": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "aud": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "nonce": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "iat": 1662888472,
    "auth_time": 1662888471,
    "idp_access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "idp": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0",
    "name": "Jad Fakhoury",
    "oid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "given_name": "Jad",
    "family_name": "Fakhoury",
    "emails": [
        "jad.fakhoury@xxxxxxx.com"
    ],
    "jobTitle": "Admin",
    "extension_Discount": "3.70",
    "tfp": "B2C_1_susi"
}
```

I send the idp_access_token to the api but i am unable to validate it, the user always has IsAuthenticated = false.

I'm using :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);
```

in my program.cs, and in my appsettings.json i have used different combinations of instance, ClientId, TenantId... but my token is never validated.
could anyone points out what am I doing wrong or what fields from the tokenClaims i should use to validate?

NB: I am able to decode the token in code and i can see the data but i am unable to validate it to use it in my controller.

Comment: can you post your API startup code? (AddJwtBearer...)

Answer (score 0):

To debug your problem you can:

1. Enable the following flag:

   .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
   {
   ...
   opt.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
   ...
   };

It will include an extra reader in the response that can give you a hint about the reason why it failed.

Like this example:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

2. You can increase the log level from authentication and authorization using these settings in **appsettings.json**:

   {
   "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Warning",
   "Microsoft": "Warning",
   "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Debug",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "Debug"
   }
   }
   }

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)